# Open CSV file in Excel having leading dash

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I have a csv file which looks like this :

```
Ref;Code;OtherData;
"MyRef";"-arm";"something";
```

I think this form is valid, isn't ?

When I open the file in Excel, the "-arm" is parsed by Excel as a formula. How can I force Excel to read the value as plain text ?

If required, I can change the CSV format.

PS: don't ask me to add a leading `'`. I don't want to adapt the value for a specific app, as other apps must still be able to read the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is import the csv into excel as "text" so go to `data - get external data - from text` (2010) and select the csv file. The import wizard will allow you to select columns and treat them with specific formats, any column with a dash or plus can be treated as text and it will not be parsed into a formula.

[image]

---

Additionally, if the data is already in excel and you don't want any formula, do a <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to find and replace all  `=` with   nothing

Comment: thanks for the tip. I was hoping a solution that can allow double clicking on the csv file with no user intervention. It's still an acceptable solution anyway

Answer (score -1):

You could just use a Find/Replace command on the source replacing `-` with a space.

Comment: This will break the csv file

Comment: Then the datum will be " arm" instead of "-arm", which is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old post, but I think what Steve is looking for could be achieved by surrounding the text with double quotes (as he has already done) and then save the csv file in UTF-8 format.

Comment: That will not solve the problem.